# Can a Groovy 4 application include a dependency built with Groovy 2.4.x?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to upgrade an application from groovy 3.0.17 to groovy 4.0.11.  This application includes a dependency built with groovy 2.4.15.  All the tests pass with groovy 3.0.17, but when I update to 4.0.11 I get test failures with NoSuchMethodErrors like:

```
'java.util.List org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure)'  
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure)'
```

The stack trace is from a line of code in the dependency that calls List.collect{}.

I first tried running with only groovy-all:4.0.11 on the classpath, then with both groovy-all:4.0.11 and groovy-all:2.4.15 included.  The test failed with the same exception either way.

Is there a way to get this groovy 2.4.15 dependency to work correctly with my groovy 4 application?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue in upgrading old projects to Groovy 4 is that the main GDK package name has been changed from "org.codehaus.*" to "org.apache.*". Not sure if in Groovy 3 the new package was already present but now in Groovy 4 the old package has been removed. If you have access to the source code of the dependency i think the best bet is to port it to Groovy 4 (in most cases it is just a matter of search and replace "org.codehaus.*" with "org.apache.*" in package imports), recompile it and include the new version in your main project that you are porting to Groovy 4.

Comment: Thanks Dario.  Unfortunately this dependency is shared between my application and a Grails 4 application.  Updating the dependency to groovy 4 results in a very similar question:  "How can I use a groovy 4 dependency in my Grails 4 (groovy 2.5.x) application?"

Comment: Can't you do maybe a "version 2" of your dependency that uses Groovy 4 (or even a fork) to use in the new project and leave the old dependency untouched so that the grails application can continue to use the old version? Unfortunately migrating a full Grails application could be a lot of effort considered the differences between version 4 and 5 (the latter still uses Groovy 3 by the way)